# Specman UVM: What is the difference between write_reg { .field == 2;}; and write_reg_fields?

Tags: verification

I'm working with `vr_ad` package for e. My question is:
What is the difference between 2 following macros for modifying registers (suppose `foo` register consists of 2 fields `field1` and `field2`):

1)

```
write_reg foo {.field1 == 1;};
```

2)

```
write_reg_fields foo {.field1 = 1};
```

I really appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

The answer I've got (thanks to user3467290) :

There is a very important difference between these forms.

In the first, the register value will be generated, using all defined constraints, + the constraint you wrote in this action (field1 == 1). The new generated value will be written to the DUT.

In the second code, what you state is that you want to modify only one field of the register - field1. What will happen is that vr_ad will get the current value of the register from the e model (the shadow model), change field1 - and will write the new value the the register in the DUT. None of the other register's fields will be changed. Also - there is no check that the value you assign to field1 complies with the constraints defined on this register.